# Get key of a specific value in a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

I made this simple code which outputs random values in the array. I hope to get the *associated key* using the fetched `randomizeValues`

```js
let characterJobList = {
  'Jack': 'Fighter',
  'Elaine': 'Healer',
  'Swift': 'Spy',
  'Teddy': 'Smith'
}

const arrayLength = Object.keys(characterJobList).length
const randomizeValues = characterJobList[Object.keys(characterJobList)[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayLength)]]

console.log(randomizeValues)
```

Comment: Just assign `Object.keys(characterJobList)[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayLength)]` to a variable and use it instead. Then you'll also have the key. Or assign `Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayLength` to a variable and use it when retrieving the key. It's a simple matter of decomposing the expression you have to reuse parts of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object.entries is a useful array.

Here I use destructuring to get the key and value in one statement

```js
let characterJobList = {
    'Jack': 'Fighter',
    'Elaine': 'Healer',
    'Swift': 'Spy',
    'Teddy': 'Smith'
}

const allEntries = Object.entries(characterJobList);
const [randomKey,randomValue] = allEntries[Math.floor(Math.random() * allEntries.length)];

console.log(randomKey, randomValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the chosen key in a separate variable before accessing the value:

```js
let characterJobList = {
    'Jack': 'Fighter',
    'Elaine': 'Healer',
    'Swift': 'Spy',
    'Teddy': 'Smith'
}

const allKeys = Object.keys(characterJobList);
const randomKey = allKeys[Math.floor(Math.random() * allKeys.length)];
const randomValue = characterJobList[randomKey];

console.log(randomKey, randomValue);
```